# Why ipa file can not be installed on iOS 11

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, ios11

I had used `xcodebuild` command to generate ipa file, and can be installed successfully on iOS 10 and below, but now install `failed` on iOS 11, and prompt me `APIInternalError` about this.

I had tried use `Xcode8.3.1` ,`Xcode8.3.3` and `Xcode9` to build my project, but its can not be installed on iOS 11 all of them.

And i tried build and archive my project manually, but its can be install successfully on iOS 11.

But why?

thanks for you answer here.

Comment: You need Xcode 9 or higher to run iOS 11. Update via the Mac App Store.

Comment: but the Release .ipa file can be installed successfully on iOS 11, and Debug .ipa file can not do that